# error with python sympy computing integral for cosine function

Tags: python, math, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, sympy

So I was trying an example directly from the sympy documentation and I am getting a strange error. I am using python 3.2 with sympy 0.7.3. I have been working in the ipython notebook, though I don't think that should make a difference. The error is that whenever I create a "x" symbol and try to integrate the math.cos(x), I get an error saying "can't convert expression to float."

Here is a code example. This is taken from the [sympy documentation](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/integrals/integrals.html).

```
import sympy
import math
x = sympy.Symbol('x')
sympy.integrate(x**2 * math.exp(x) * math.cos(x), x)
```

The error message that results is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-123-84e55454fb60> in <module>()
----> 1 sympy.integrate(x**2 * math.exp(x) * math.cos(x), x)

/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/sympy/core/expr.py in __float__(self)
242         if result.is_number and result.as_real_imag()[1]:
243             raise TypeError("can't convert complex to float")
--> 244         raise TypeError("can't convert expression to float")
245 
246     def __complex__(self):

TypeError: can't convert expression to float
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Try using `sympy.exp` and `sympy.cos` instead of `math.exp` and `math.cos`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot mix the symbolic mathematical expressions created by the `sympy` library with normal functions that just calculate a value (like the ones from the `math` library. If you're creating a symbolic expression, you should always use the `sympy` functions (`sympy.exp`, `sympy.cos`, `sympy.log`, etc.):

```
x = sympy.Symbol('x')
sympy.integrate(x**2 * sympy.exp(x) * sympy.cos(x), x)
```

Operators such as `*`, `+`, `-`... Are overloaded by objects in  the `sympy` library so you can use them in your expressions, but you cannot use normal functions that directly calculate values.