# Solving set of exponential equations in python

Tags: python, numpy, math, exponential, equations

Trying to solve a set of exponential equations but keep getting errors saying that "can't convert float" or "float is not callable"

You may run the code, just replace the variables with any values you'd like.

```
from sympy.abc import x, y
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp
import math 

A0 = 58
G0 = 44
Gmax = 117
tmax = 40

s=[((sp.log(x) - sp.log(y)) - (tmax*(x-y))), (Gmax- G0 - (A0 * x /(y-x))*((sp.exp((-x)*tmax)) - (sp.exp((-y)*tmax))))]
sp.solve(s, x, y)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error with python sympy computing integral for cosine function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18267470/error-with-python-sympy-computing-integral-for-cosine-function)

Comment: @Salchem Please provide a Minimum Working Example (MWE), so that the code you have posted can work on anybodies system. For instance, I cannot run `all_training_df` nor `solve_poly_system`. I do not know where those objects come from.

Comment: Ok, see above, I replaced them

Comment: I get the following error:    could not solve -73*(y + LambertW(-40*y*exp(-40*y))/40)*exp(40*y)*exp(-LambertW(-40*y*exp(-40*y))) - 29*(exp(40*y) - exp(-LambertW(-40*y*exp(-40*y))))*LambertW(-40*y*exp(-40*y))/20

Answer (score 1):

remove the math and use sympy for log and exp

```
from sympy.abc import x, y
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp
Gmax = np.amax(all_training_df.iloc[1])
tmax = np.argmax(all_training_df.iloc[1])
A0 = all_combined_df.iloc[1]['CHO (g)']
G0 = all_combined_df.iloc[1]['mg/dL']
s=[((sp.log(x) - sp.log(y)) - (tmax*(x-y))), (Gmax- G0 - (A0 * x /(y-x))*((sp.exp((-x)*tmax)) - (sp.exp((-y)*tmax))))]
sp.solve_poly_system(s, x, y)
```

Comment: Yea, tried that but it gives "could not solve -73*(y + LambertW .........."  See above